# Azure powershell calculating metrics for webapp

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to calculate metric for all the web app inside a subscription using get-azmetric cmdlet and I am using -aggregation type parameter so how can we apply more than one aggregation type in -aggregation type parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you could not apply more than one aggregation type in this parameter, the [`AggregationType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.monitor.models.aggregationtype?view=azure-dotnet) just accepts only one value in one time, also see the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-3.5.0#parameters).

[image]

Your option is to run the command several times like below.

```
Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "<ResourceId>" -MetricName "CpuTime" -AggregationType Average

Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "<ResourceId>" -MetricName "CpuTime" -AggregationType Count
```

**Update**:

```
$types = @("Average", "Count", "Minimum", "Maximum", "Total")
$types | ForEach {Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "ResourceId" -MetricName "CpuTime" -AggregationType $_}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this parameter accepts piping input any idea how can I provide multiple aggregation type through piping

Comment: @S.k See my update, the script will traversal the different types in `$types` with the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks joy,but If I use this command for multiple webapps about 30 then it will be very slow

Comment: @S.k Yes, but I think there are no other better ideas, we could just traversal the 30 web apps.

Comment: Is there any another way for calculating metrics for a large number of web apps or asp webapps

Comment: @S.k AFAIK, there is no such way.